# "close" event did not fire in server sent events(sse) if i serve the index.html in the same origin

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I'm trying to make some demo with [server-sent-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), here is my code:
index.js

```js
import http from "http";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const { url, method } = req;
  if (url === "/" && method === "GET") {
    res.writeHead(200, "ok", {
      "content-type": "text/html",
    });
    fs.createReadStream("./index.html")
      .pipe(res);
    return;
  } else if (url === "/favicon.ico" && method === "GET") {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
    return;
  } else if (url === "/sse") {
    if (method !== "GET") {
      res.writeHead(405);
      res.end("method not allowed");
      return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "content-type": "text/event-stream",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
    });
    
    req.addListener("close", () => {
      console.log("close");
    });
    res.write("event: ping\n");
    res.write("data: hello world!\n\n");
    return;
  }

  // other url will be redirect to /
  res.writeHead(301, {
    location: "/"
  });
  res.end();
}).listen(8888, () => {
  console.log("\n\thttp://0.0.0.0:8888\n");
});
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2>NodeJs HTTP</h2>
  </div>
  <script>
    const url = "/sse"; // if I use this relative url, then the listener in index.js will not fire. Why?
    // const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/sse"; // if I use absolute url, everything works fine.
    const sse = new EventSource(url);
    sse.addEventListener("open", function(e) {
      console.log(e)
    });
    sse.addEventListener("ping", function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
    sse.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
    sse.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works as expected if I use absolute url in the index.html:

1. When I refresh/close current tab in browser, the console should log a string `close`.

But if I use relative url, these is not output in the console. And I want to know why is this happen?

Answer (score 0):

OK! I know what has happened now.
It was my VPN cause this problem, it change the connection field in response headers from "keep-alive" to "close"!!!
So I get another problem now...